# React Native Image URI Not Showing

Tags: ios, image, uri, react-native

While rendering a set of row components in ListView, my uri images seem not to be showing up at all. I have included Image in the react module. My custom component is the following:

```
var url = rowData.mediaGroups[0].contents[0].url; 
            if (url.indexOf('w=150') > -1)
            {
                url.replace("w=150", "w=500");
            }
            return <ArticlePreview
                category={rowData.categories[0]}
                key={sectionID}
                heartText={'2.9k'}
                categoryPress={this.onCategoryDetailsPress}
                selected={false}
                source={{ uri: url }}
                text={rowData.title.toLowerCase().replace('&nbsp;','')}
                onPress={this.onArticleDetailsPress} />
```

The component has multiple properties and is used throughout my app (and works there with link images). But for some reason the component just stopped working in the app for uri images. Not sure what to do. Here is the code for the component itself:

```
//component for article preview touchable image
/* will require the following
- rss feed and api
- user's keyword interests from parse In home.js
- parse db needs to be augmented to include what they heart
- parse db needs to be augmented to include what they press on (like google news)
*/
var React = require('react-native');
var {
  View, 
  StyleSheet, 
  Text, 
  Image, 
  TouchableHighlight, 
} = React;

//dimensions
var Dimensions = require('Dimensions');
var window = Dimensions.get('window');
var ImageButton = require('../../common/imageButton');
var KeywordBox = require('../../authentication/onboarding/keyword-box');

//additional libraries

module.exports = React.createClass({
  //onPress function that triggers when button pressed
  //this.props.text is property that can be dynamically filled within button 
  /* following props:
    - source={this.props.source}
    - onPress={this.props.onPress}
    - {this.props.text}
    - {this.props.heartText}
    - key={this.props.key} 
    - text={this.props.category} 
    - this.props.selected
  */
  render: function() {
    return (
      <TouchableHighlight 
        underlayColor={'transparent'}
        onPress={this.props.onPress} >
          <Image source={this.props.source} style={[styles.articlePreview, this.border('red')]}>
                  <View style={[styles.container, this.border('organge')]}>
                      <View style={[styles.header, this.border('blue')]}>
                          <Text style={[styles.previewText]}>{this.props.text}</Text>
                      </View>
                      <View style={[styles.footer, this.border('white')]}>
                        <View style={[styles.heartRow, this.border('black')]}>
                          <ImageButton
                              style={[styles.heartBtn, , this.border('red')]}
                              resizeMode={'contain'}
                              onPress={this.onHeartPress}
                              source={require('../../img/heart_btn.png')} />
                          <Text style={[styles.heartText]}>{this.props.heartText} favorites</Text>
                        </View>
                          <KeywordBox 
                              style={[styles.category, this.border('blue')]}
                              key={this.props.key} 
                              text={this.props.category} 
                              onPress={this.props.categoryPress}
                              selected={this.props.selected} />
                      </View>
                  </View>
          </Image>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    );
  }, 
  onHeartPress: function() {
    //will move this function to a general module
  }, 
  border: function(color) {
      return {
        //borderColor: color, 
        //borderWidth: 4,
      } 
   },
});

var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  heartText: {
    color: 'white', 
    fontSize: 12, 
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    alignSelf: 'center', 
    marginLeft: 5, 
  }, 
  heartRow: {
    flexDirection: 'row', 
    justifyContent: 'space-around', 
    alignSelf: 'center', 
    justifyContent: 'center', 
  }, 
  heartBtn: {
    height: (92/97)*(window.width/13), 
    width: window.width/13, 
    alignSelf:'center', 
  }, 
  category: {
    fontFamily: 'Bebas Neue', 
    fontSize: 10,
    fontWeight: 'bold'
  }, 
  header: {
    flex: 3, 
    alignItems: 'center', 
    justifyContent: 'space-around', 
    marginTop: window.height/30,
  }, 
  footer: {
    flex: 1, 
    flexDirection: 'row', 
    justifyContent: 'space-between', 
    alignItems: 'center', 
    margin: window.height/50,
  }, 
  container: {
    flex: 1, 
    backgroundColor: 'black', 
    opacity: 0.6, 
  }, 
  articlePreview: {
    flex: 1, 
    height: window.height/3.2, 
    width: window.width, 
    flexDirection: 'column'
  }, 
  previewText: {
    fontFamily: 'Bebas Neue', 
    fontSize: 23,
    color: 'white', 
    alignSelf: 'center', 
    textAlign: 'center', 
    margin: 5, 
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    left: 0
  }, 

});
```

The UI currently looks like this with not images (has black background):

[image]

Comment: Can you give us the result of this.props.source ? Also, is there a reason you are wrapping other components inside your image component? Thanks.

Comment: hey @NaderDabit, I have nested components in my custom component so that I can get the text on top of the image - this is to make an article preview for the user - but the problem that that gives me is when i change the opacity of the image (to darken it so the text is more easily visible), it changes the opacity on the text itself. I tried to use the react-native-overlay component that bretvante made but it isn't very good (has positioning issues). Do you have any advice to reconcile the opacity issue? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Checked my rss feeds - some were unreliable resulting in messing with the way the images were being shown